# Dynamic Comparison Operators in Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In B3, I have this formula: =B2&REGEXEXTRACT(G2,"=|<>"&C2). And the result I get is: 1=2. However, I need the result to be either TRUE or FALSE.

I tried using =TRUE(B2&REGEXEXTRACT(G2,"=|<>"&C2)), but I receive an error.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyKnb.png)

I need the result to be either TRUE or FALSE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that your formula generates a string result, and there's no simple way to force the evaluation of a string as a formula in Google Sheets. A hacky approach is to abuse QUERY, because the select string is in text format:

```
=not(iserror(query({B2,C2},"select Col1 where Col1"&G2&"Col2",0)))
```

What is happening here is that the QUERY returns the value in Col1 (B2) if the comparison is TRUE or an #N/A error if it is false; ISERROR will therefore return the 'wrong' answer, and so NOT flips the answer to the correct one.

Comment: I'm always getting false, even if I change the operator in G2 to <> or if I change C2 to the same value as B1.

Comment: Could you possibly share your sheet where you are seeing this problem, as it appears to be working OK at my end?

Comment: Worked. I just have an issue to convert the formula to my country. Thanks.